# What triggers a function call in other column when ngmodel changes in first column?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Consider the snippet:

**JS**

```
var mod = angular.module('module', []);
mod.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'aLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'aSubItem'
        }
    }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'bLabel',
        subItem: {
            name: 'bSubItem'
        }
    }]

    $scope.getValue = function(ngmodel) {
        // some code goes here...
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller='controller'>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat='count in counter'> // 5 times
                <td>
                    <select ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in items" 
                            ng-model="selected[$index]">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{getValue(1)}}
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

As soon as I select some value from the dropdown (select tag) in the first column, I notice that the function in the second column is triggered? What is the reason for this? What exactly is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are doing it inside ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat = 'count in counter'>
```

You need to pass the object on the controller, in order to do some action on the same.

```
 {{getValue(obj)}}
```

Comment: I am not asking what/how to do something in the controller when the function call is triggered, but how does the call got triggered. Does ng-repeat causes the other child elements to be triggered when one of the child notices some change in the same row.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari The reason is because its inside the ng-repeat, whatever gets applied to first element will get applied to all the elements in the array